# Javascript variable not found

Tags: javascript, asp.net

i have the script on ASPX:

```
<dx:ASPxButton ID="ASPxButton_PrintLetrVoit" runat="server" Text="Impression lettre de voiture(décalage)" AutoPostBack="False">
      <ClientSideEvents Click="function (s, e) { e.processOnServer = false; for (var i = 0; i < Tourne.length; i++) {window.open('PrintLettreVoit.aspx?TourneId='+Tourne[i]);}}" />
</dx:ASPxButton>
```

and in cs :

```
public List<string> Tourne;

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
      try
      {
          foreach (var oItem in oOrdre_BL.GetAllLettrVoit_Tourne())
          {
           Page.ClientScript.RegisterArrayDeclaration("Tourne", "'"+oItem+"'");
          }
      ......
```

unfortunately i got Error on javascript:
i got error:

```
Horodatage : 06/09/2012 11:23:03
Erreur : ReferenceError: Tourne is not defined
Fichier Source : http://xxxxxxx/Code/BackEnd/FaExped_BackEnd_WebSite/Ordre.aspx
Ligne : 5146
```

any idea ?

Thanks you in advance

PS: when i see the source code that generated:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
var Tourne =  new Array('');
//]]>
</script>


<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[

WebForm_InitCallback();//]]>
</script>
</form>


</body>
</html>
```

i have modified my code:

```
 <dx:ASPxButton ID="ASPxButton_PrintLetrVoit" runat="server" Text="Impression lettre de voiture(décalage)" AutoPostBack="False">
                          <ClientSideEvents Click="function (s, e) {   
                          if(typeof(Tourne) !== 'undefined' && Tourne != null) 
                          {
                            e.processOnServer = false; 

                             for (var i = 0; i < Tourne.length; i++) {window.open('PrintLettreVoit.aspx?TourneId='+Tourne[i]);}
                          }
                          else
                          {alert ('Tous est coches');}

                             }" />
                        </dx:ASPxButton>
```

but still, it is not a good solution, because i don't know why Tourne is undefined?

Comment: I thing you just declared `public List<string> Tourne;` but you need to give a definition before using that. (I'm not a .net developper)

Comment: Just an idea for a better coding style: Don't insert a complete Javascript function into an eventhandler. Reduced to the method call.

Answer (score 0):

It *could* be that you have some single-quotes in the data.  The reason that's a a problem is as follows:

When you call "Page.ClientScript.RegisterArrayDeclaration" it adds that item to a JavaScript array declaration at the bottom of the page.

So, the following:

```
Page.ClientScript.RegisterArrayDeclaration("Tourne", "'a'");
Page.ClientScript.RegisterArrayDeclaration("Tourne", "'b'");
Page.ClientScript.RegisterArrayDeclaration("Tourne", "'c'");
```

Would render the following JavaScript on-page:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
var Tourne =  new Array('a', 'b', 'c');
//]]>
</script>
```

If there are any single-quotes in the data that's returned by "oOrdre_BL.GetAllLettrVoit_Tourne()", then it would insert those.  So, if I added a fourth element of "'brok'en'" (invalid because it's got an extra single-quote):

```
Page.ClientScript.RegisterArrayDeclaration("Tourne", "'brok'en'");
```

Then it would render the following invalid JavaScript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
var Tourne =  new Array('a', 'b', 'c', 'brok'en');
//]]>
</script>
```

If this occurs, then "Tourne" will never properly get defined because the JavaScript is invalid.  As such, you should be "cleansing" your data before trying to put it in the array.  The following should work to "escape" the single-quote:

```
Page.ClientScript.RegisterArrayDeclaration("Tourne", "'" + oItem.Replace("'", "\\'") + "'");
```

Of course, this is based on the assumption of bad data.  If that doesn't work, the best thing to do is to "view source" in your browser when looking at the page.  Have a look at the bottom of the markup where "Tourne" is defined in JavaScript, and post that here - it should help figure out what's going on.

Comment: Thanks you but it is not because of the ' or ''

Comment: In which case, please can you follow the suggestion in the last paragraph of my reply so that we can investigate further?

Answer (score 0):

I experienced the same issue and I found that my page is inside an update panel which was creating the problem. I had to disable the partial rendering property of script manager like below:

```
<telerik:RadScriptManager ID="radScriptManager1" runat="server" EnablePartialRendering="false"/>
```